# How can I pass session from one servlet to another

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet ,it creates the session and I need to pass that session to another servlet,
Is that possible ?

Comment: just a suggestion if you just started learning JSP/Servlets pls go through Head First Servlet Jsp it explains all the basic concepts clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can.**

Sessions are not specific to a servlet it is `managed by your servlet container.` So even if you forward request from one servlet to another and use  `request.getSession()`the session will persist, provided you dont call the `invalidate()` or `session timeout` didn't occurs and both the servlets belong to same web application.

To add on :
When the first request comes from a user he is assigned a session and all further request\response will have in same session unless the session expires either due to session timeout or `invalidate()` method was called. The container manages session with two methods:

1. URL Rewriting.
2. Cookies.